# ZF3 Navigation "plugin" error

Tags: php, zend-framework3, zend-navigation

Following https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-navigation/quick-start/, i try to make a navigation for my application. I registered a navigation, i added the DefaultNavigationFactory to the service-manager, but i get an error when i try to print the navigation.

This is my module/Application/config/module.config.php:

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;
use Zend\View\Helper\Navigation;

return [
'navigation' => [
    'default' => [
        /* ... */
    ]
] ,

'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        'navigation' => DefaultNavigationFactory::class,
    ],
],
];
```

But when `$this->navigation('default')->menu()`, i get this error, excluding the stack trace:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: A plugin by the name "navigation" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\View\HelperPluginManager in C:\Users\bikke_000\Documents\Sites\slapenenzo\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php:133
```

Answer (score 4):

Running

`composer require zendframework/zend-navigation`

fixed the issue it seems that in zf3 navigation isn't installed by default

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer of @Ponsjuh I had to include the module "Zend\Navigation" in my modules config.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass 'navigation' instead of 'default' as below:

```
 $this->navigation('navigation')->menu();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your "development mode". In production mode, 'config_cache_enabled' is true. When you install new module, you must refresh cache.
Default: 'data/cache/module-config-cache.application.config.cache.php'